# smartgwt xml value/attribute/tag map to object

Tags: xml, smartgwt

Given the following XML entity:

```
<reportRow key="1181">
<reportCell name="objId">1181</reportCell>
<reportCell name="objName">test1</reportCell>
<reportCell name="parentObjFullName">testsys</reportCell>
</reportRow>
```

How can I get the value of "objName"? I've tried with the following but it's empty.

```
DataSourceField objName = new DataSourceField("objName", FieldType.TEXT, "Name");
```

XPath is set correctly (setRecordXPath("/report/reportRows/reportRow");).

Any idea?

Kind regards